# OnTextChangedListener on programmatically added edit text does not work correctly

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have created a Edit text programmatically and added a text watcher to it, my code is shown below:

```
txtPrice = new EditText(this);
txtPrice.setHint("Price");
txtPrice.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
txtPrice.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
txtPrice.setTextSize(20);
txtPrice.setPadding(20, 0, 0, 0);
txtPrice.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
txtPrice.addTextChangedListener(new NumberTextWatcher(txtPrice));
txtPrice.setFilters(new InputFilter[] { new InputFilter.LengthFilter(9) });
txtPrice.setInput
Type(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

This class adds a comma to any number added eg: `1,356,785` when I add it to an edit text that is defined normally:

```
@Override
public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
    et.removeTextChangedListener(this);

    try {
        int inilen, endlen;
        inilen = et.getText().length();

        String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");
        Number n = df.parse(v);
        int cp = et.getSelectionStart();
        if (hasFractionalPart) {
            et.setText(df.format(n));
        } else {
            et.setText(dfnd.format(n));
        }
        endlen = et.getText().length();
        int sel = (cp + (endlen - inilen));
        if (sel > 0 && sel <= et.getText().length()) {
            et.setSelection(sel);
        } else {
            // place cursor at the end?
            et.setSelection(et.getText().length() - 1);
        }
    } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
        // do nothing?
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // do nothing?
    }

    et.addTextChangedListener(this);
}
```

At the moment it only adds a blank space. Does anyone have any help or suggestions for me? I do not understand why this does not want to work.

Comment: possible that you have forget to add the "," ? Here : String v = s.toString().replace(String.valueOf(df.getDecimalFormatSymbols().getGroupingSeparator()), "");

Comment: @Opiatefuchs I checked, but the code already works on a normal edit text and not on a edit text that is added programmatically. I dont know how to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

Type(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER); might be preventing it from changing to commas since it only allows for numbers.

Comment: I tried to comment the line out, but it make no difference, thanx for the suggestion though